# Contain Method for all occurrences

Tags: java, string, contains

How can I use the `String.contains("string")` method for all occurrences of a word in a string, not just the first occurrence of the word?

Comment: If there was a method for **counting** the occurrences of one string in another, it would **not** be called `contains` - which implies a boolean of either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

String.contains   only return Boolean.

If you want count the occurrence of string

```
String str = "java string contain return boolean. java java";
String findStr = "java";
int lastIndex = 0;
int count = 0;
while(lastIndex != -1){
lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);
if(lastIndex != -1){
   count ++;
   lastIndex += findStr.length();
 }
}
System.out.println(count);
```